# Proper way to exit from recursive loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops

I am trying to write a program to identify the occurrences of 3 consecutive integers in a given array of N numbers and replace them with the middle value by deleting the other two.
For example Input->55 99 99 100 101 101 34 35 36 5 28 7 50 50 51 52 52 24 13 14 15 5 6 7 37 31 37 38 39 36 40
Output->55 100 35 5 28 7 51 24 14 6 37 31 38 36 40

To achieve this i wrote this method which accepts array as an input and it returns the modified array.

```
//input 
int[] original = new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8} ;

            List<int> lstoriginal = new List<int>(original);
            List<int> modified = Test(lstoriginal);

//method
    public static List<int> Test(List<int> arrayInput)
        {

            for (i = 0; i < arrayInput.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i + 2 < arrayInput.Count)
                {
                    if (arrayInput[i + 2] == arrayInput[i + 1] + 1
                    && arrayInput[i + 2] == arrayInput[i] + 2)
                    {
                        arrayInput.RemoveAt(i + 2);
                        arrayInput.RemoveAt(i);
                        List<int> temp = arrayInput;
                        Test(temp);
                    }
                }
            }

            return arrayInput;


        }
```

Follwoing are the execution steps/result which i analyzed-

1-Initially if the test input is 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8

2-When i=1 and it finds that 3,4,5 is in sequence it removes 3 and 5 and list becomes 1,4,5,6,8

3-Next time when i=1 then it finds 4,5,6 and it removes 4 and 6 and the new list is 1,5,8

4-i am expecting to exit from loop when i + 2 < arrayInput.Count returns false and trying to retrun the modified array immediately here the return statement gets executed but instead of return the result it again calls the  Test(temp); statement few more times and then get exit. Please suggest

Comment: can it be another code, or you want it to be with `for` and so on ?

Comment: and it will always have just 3 elements? or can be n-elements, and you always want to return (all elements) except the smaller and the bigger? Or always return all except the first and the last ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need recursion at all.  You can perform the task significantly faster by just moving `i` after you're removed your sequence.  Here's a function that is much simpler and does the exact same thing.  I tested it on tens of thousands of randomly generated unordered sequences.

```
public static List<int> Test2(List<int> arrayInput)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayInput.Count - 2; i++)
    {
        if (arrayInput[i + 2] == arrayInput[i + 1] + 1
        && arrayInput[i + 2] == arrayInput[i] + 2)
        {
            arrayInput.RemoveAt(i + 2);
            arrayInput.RemoveAt(i);
            i = Math.Max(-1, i - 3); // -1 'cause i++ in loop will increment it
        }
    }

    return arrayInput;
}
```

That said, to answer your specific question, the best way to exit a recursive loop like your original is to change the signature of your recursive function to return a `bool` indicating whether or not it actually made any changes.  When the first one returns with no changes, they all can exist, so your call to `Test` can be wrapped in `if (!Test(...)) { return; }`.

Here's the complete test and test data comparing your original to my modified version:

```
public static void Main()
{
    const int COUNT = 10000;
    var r = new Random();
    int matchCount = 0;

    var stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
    var stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();

    for (int j = 0; j < COUNT; j++)
    {
        var list = new List<int>(100) {1};

        for(int k=1; k<100; k++)
        {
            switch(r.Next(5))
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    list.Add(list[k - 1] + 1);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    list.Add(list[k - 1] + r.Next(2));
                    break;

                case 4:
                    list.Add(list[k - 1] - r.Next(5));
                    break;
            }
        }

        stopwatch1.Start();
        List<int> copy1 = Test1(new List<int>(list));
        stopwatch1.Stop();

        stopwatch2.Start();
        List<int> copy2 = Test2(new List<int>(list));
        stopwatch2.Stop();


        string list1 = String.Join(",", copy1);
        string list2 = String.Join(",", copy2);

        if (list1 == list2)
        {
            if (copy1.Count == list.Count)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No change:" + list1);
            }
            else
            {
                matchCount++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MISMATCH:");
            Console.WriteLine("   Orig  : " + String.Join(",", list));
            Console.WriteLine("   Test1 : " + list1);
            Console.WriteLine("   Test2 : " + list2);
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Matches: " + matchCount);
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed 1: {0:#,##0} ms", stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed 2: {0:#,##0} ms", stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}



public static List<int> Test1(List<int> arrayInput)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayInput.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i + 2 < arrayInput.Count)
        {
            if (arrayInput[i + 2] == arrayInput[i + 1] + 1
            && arrayInput[i + 2] == arrayInput[i] + 2)
            {
                arrayInput.RemoveAt(i + 2);
                arrayInput.RemoveAt(i);
                List<int> temp = arrayInput;
                Test1(temp);
            }
        }
        else
        {      // modified part: return the array
            return arrayInput;
        }
    }

    return arrayInput;
}

//method
public static List<int> Test2(List<int> arrayInput)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayInput.Count - 2; i++)
    {
        if (arrayInput[i + 2] == arrayInput[i + 1] + 1
        && arrayInput[i + 2] == arrayInput[i] + 2)
        {
            arrayInput.RemoveAt(i + 2);
            arrayInput.RemoveAt(i);
            i = Math.Max(-1, i - 3); // -1 'cause i++ in loop will increment it
        }
    }

    return arrayInput;
}
```

Comment: @Samuel- Thanks for the optimized solution but the logic suggeted by you fails in some cases for example if for the input- 100, 98, 99, 99, 100, 101, 98 the output should 100,99,98 but it return 100,98,99,100,101 -it does not remove the last occurence of consecutive integers.

Comment: @DJay, I overlooked the fact that the original lists are not sequential.  The only change necessary to account for this is to decrement `i` by three each time you remove two items.  I updated my answer and added significantly more test data based on the clarified business rules.

Comment: @Samuel-I was assigning i =0 whenever i find consecutive numbers. It's working but it's not optimized approach as compared to yours i= Math.Max(-1, i - 3); this one is working perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DJay, great, I'm glad it helped. Please mark this as the right answer if it answered your question (click the check mark). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please define "cannot exit".  Do you mean the for keeps looping indefinitely?  I don't see that happening from this code.

What it looks like to me:

This function will:
Step through the input, int by int.  Checks to see if this int and the next 2 are sequential.  Then it removes this one and the one after next, then feeds the result back into this same function.  It then ignores any value this may have given us and continues on its merry way.

You have an input of 8,9,10
It starts to step through: i = 0 and all that.
so it finds that 8,9,10 are sequential, it then removes 8 and 9 and feeds that result into this same function.

So we start over again:

You have an input of 9
It starts to step through: i = 0 again.
it steps through and finds that there are not at least 3 values in the list, and returns the original.

We then completely ignore that result and continue the original loop above.  Now i = 1, but there's only 1 thing in the arrayInput anymore, so it should end.

From what you're doing, I see no reason to make a recursive call.  You're not doing anything with the result and even if you were, it would only help you if you had a collection like 8,9,10,10,11.  Then the first call would trim it down to 9,10,11 and the recursive call would trim it down to 10